# Design Approach With Data Containing Several Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am designing an application which will process statistics data and produce various visual and data outputs. The current data has around 1500 records, but around 3000 columns! All the columns are important and will be required by the system.

The database of choice is SQL Server. The issue is that SQL server limits each table to 1024 columns. I could normalize the data to 5 tables of 600 columns each. The issue with this is that I have not found a way to import more than 250 columns into SQL  server. Does anyone have any suggestions as to a better design? Or a method to actually import all these columns? I do not expect detrimental performance issues as a lot of the data in the columns will be NULL.

Comment: We'd have to know more about the actual data to give reasonable recommendations.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Its just a large data set with each record representing a person and each field representing a question asked from a questionnaire. So most of the data is either 1 or NULL or a character

Comment: So, 1500 records with 3000 columns, each of which is probably representable as one byte? That's less than 5MB. Why not just load the whole thing into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to store the data in a table?  Or can you handle your processing on the fly?  Not sure what your response-time requirements are, but if it's only 1500 rows, maybe you can just handle all your data processing real-time using a stored procedure/function:

1. Import data into an array-structure
2. Process data from array
3. Run whatever query results you need

Or maybe a better option, depending on if your DB supports it - store the columns for each row as a JSON / array data type.  Then you could do everything from one table.

I'd say your best bet, though, is to create three tables (each with the same row PK) and multiple import jobs.  Then just join the tables to get all the columns into one result set.

Answer (score 0):

> > SQL server limits each table to 1024 columns

No it doesn't.  The limit is 30,000, but you have to make it a "[wide table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tables)"

**Wide Tables**

> Wide tables use sparse columns to increase the total of
>   columns that a table can have to 30,000. Sparse columns are ordinary
>   columns that have an optimized storage for null values. Sparse columns
>   reduce the space requirements for null values at the cost of more
>   overhead to retrieve nonnull values. A wide table has defined a column
>   set, which is an untyped XML representation that combines all the
>   sparse columns of a table into a structured output. The number of
>   indexes and statistics is also increased to 1,000 and 30,000,
>   respectively. The maximum size of a wide table row is 8,019 bytes.
>   Therefore, most of the data in any particular row should be NULL. The
>   maximum number of nonsparse columns plus computed columns in a wide
>   table remains 1,024.

Or you could use XML or JSON to store many of the attributes in a semi-structured document if you prefer.